# Can writing to an output ksds be done if we use alternate key concept with dynamic access mode in a input ksds?

Tags: cobol, mainframe, jcl, vsam

I have an input KSDS file, i am using emp-id as primary key and emp-dept as alternate key, with access mode as dynamic. I am reading the file using dynamic access base upon the alternate key, in runjcl i am using base ksds file and ksds path file, so normally cobol will read from the path file
(which is sorted based upon the alternate key not the primary key).

but problem is while i am writing to an output ksds it is showing file status 21 error, because 
in ksds record can only be inserted if it is sorted based upon the primary key, so what to do? is there any other alternate method??

Comment: Assuming that you do return to see if anyone has said anything, go with Bruce's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not

1. Write the output to a normal Sequential file
2. Sort copy the sequential file into the output VSAM file.

If updating an existing file, you should be able to update the file. Alternatively you can always use 2 programs and sort the output from the first program.

Does the output file really need to be a VSAM file ???.

Comment: output is a vsam file , thanks , i will use a temporary ps file to write the records first, but is there any direct way to directly write to a output ksds while using alternate key concept cause my input ksds got huge set of records.

Comment: For an initial load, having a separate sort step will be the most efficient